# My app get stop when auto lock,how can it be sorted

Tags: java, android

```
package my.app.bhaktamar;
import android.app.Activity;
//import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
//import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
//import android.view.View;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        MediaPlayer dontcall;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("Pickle", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.e("pickle", "onResume");
        dontcall = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gpad1);
        dontcall.start();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e("pickle", "onPause");
        dontcall.stop();
        dontcall.release();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

What should i do so sound should play after autolock ?

Answer (score 1):

use stop mediaplayer  content in `ondestroy()` in your activity,so when your close activity  after then the mediaplayer will stop.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{ 
    dontcall.stop();
    dontcall.release();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: But my qus is it Stop on AutoLock i dont want app to stop on Autolock

Comment: by adding in XML file       android:keepScreenOn="true"> 
 is that work,let me try , i hope it work

Comment: if you got your solutions , nice too.... `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`you can use like this also in your class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Service to play music background. If you want to play after autolock, use WakeLock.